# Appending list in Python

Tags: python, list, oop

I am trying to create a method that allows each instance of the class to be "neighbors" of each other. If Entity A adds B as a neighbor, then B is in A's **neighbor_list**. However,  as the output below shows, B is automatically added to B's neighbor list and that's not the desired behavior - B's neighbor list should be empty. Any thoughts?

Output:

```
 a's neighbor list element: b
 b's neighbor list element: b
```

Code:

```
 class Entities:
     neighbor_list = []
     name = ''

     def __init__(self,name):
         self.name = name

     def add (self, neighbor):
         self.neighbor_list.append(neighbor)  

 a = Entities ('a')
 b = Entities ('b')
 a.add(b)
 print "a's neighbor list element: %s" % a.neighbor_list[0].name
 print "b's neighbor list element: %s" % b.neighbor_list[0].name
```

Comment: Why does it surprise you that mutating a class attribute means that all instances can see the mutation?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Well, presumably what surprises him is that `neighbor_list` _is_ a class member rather than an instance member, because he assumed that Python did members exactly like, say, Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `neighbor_list` an instance, not class, attribute:

```
class Entities(object):
    # not here
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbor_list = [] # here
```

Class attributes, defined outside the instance methods, are shared by all instances of the class.